# Change behaviour of many2many field in odoo 12

Tags: python, odoo

I write this question after much search without finding any answer.

So as in one2many field after adding `editable="top/bottom"` is able to create record in same form. My question: is it possible for many2many field? Meaning in many2many field there is create and edit option.

After clicking on create and edit it will pop up default model form view, but i don't want it. After click on create and edit option it will able to display any other custom form view or it will display other form field where many2many field is available.

Is it possible? If yes how's it possible and if not is any other alternative way available.

I have attached screenshot in click on red highlighted part it will redirect to green highlighted part.

Please help. Thanks in advance for your time.

[image]

Comment: I can't understand your actual requirement. Can you please described which type of behavior you want for many2many field?

Comment: In screenshot 2 parts are highlighted one is red and one is green. After click on red part(create edit option of many2many field) it will render to form view of many2many model. but I don't want to open form view instead it will render to field on same form where many2many field is available that is green highlighted part. Hope you understand

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible to specify witch `form` should the `many2one` show when creating or editing a record, it's by using `context` attribute:

```xml
<field name="your_many2one_field_name"
         context="{'form_view_ref':'app_name.xmlID_of_form'}" />
```

This spacial key works also for x2many field and there is other like `tree_view_ref, kanban_view_ref`.

There is no easy way to do what you want by default clicking on `create and edit button` or `open button` opens a form `view`.